# Add www after http/https using urlparse in python

Tags: python

I want to add www after HTTP/https in particular URL. Here is my code:

```
import urllib
from urllib.parse import urlunsplit

def addhttps(url):
    replaced=urllib.parse.urlsplit(url)
    if replaced.scheme=='http' or replaced.scheme=='https' or replaced.scheme=='':
        replaced = replaced._replace(scheme="https")
    return replaced.geturl()

def addWWW(url):
    replaced=urllib.parse.urlsplit(url)
    if replaced.netloc=='':
        replaced = replaced._replace(netloc="www")
    return replaced.geturl()

s="example.com"
c=addhttps(s)
d=addWWW(c)

print(c)
print(d)
```

I am getting output which i don't want:

```
https:///example.com
https://www/example.com
```

I am expecting output like this:

```
https://example.com
https://www.example.com
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using urlparse(tested in python2.7)

```
from urlparse import urlparse
s="example.com"
o = urlparse(s)
print "https://www.{0}".format(o.path)
```

returns

```
https://www.example.com
```